# Are additive zero and additive identity the same thing?

Tags: abstract-algebra, semiring

> **Edit:** In a semiring $(R, +, \cdot, 0, 1)$, $0$ and $1$ are additive identity and multiplicative identity, respectively such that $0$ is multiplicatively absorbing, that is $0\cdot a=0=a\cdot 0$ for all $a\in R$ and $1$ is additively absorbing (in particular), that is $1+a=1=a+1$.

I doubt $1$ is also called additive zero? Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: But it's not true that $1+a=1=a+1$. Are you sure you have it right?

Comment: This is a bizarre definition. Is this a true or false question? I've never heard of $1$ being additively absorbing.

Comment: He is defining a boolean ring here.  Multiplication is the "and" operation while addition is the "or" operation.  Then  $1$ is additively absorbing.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde i assume $1\noteq 0$. Is it correct to call $1$ (being multiplicative identity or, additively absorbing element) as additive zero? In short: Are additive zero and additively absorbing element the same?

Comment: @GEdgar Pointed right. The operations  i am considering are of Boolean ring or,  idempotent semiring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$0$ is multiplicatively absorbing in a ring, which can easily be shown. For instance, let $R$ be a ring and $a\in R.$ Then since $0$ is an additive identity, $a0=a(0+0)=a0+a0\Rightarrow a0=0.$ Similarly, $0a=0.$

However, the additive identity $0$ is not additively absorbing. That would mean that $\forall a\in R,$ $0+a=a+0=0,$ which is obviously false.

In a ring, $0$ is just notation for the additive identity, so it doesn't have to be $0.$ It could be $1.$ The term "additive zero" is much less conventional than "additive identity," even though $0$ is often referred to as the additive identity. The multiplicative identity or unity is often written as $1,$ though it may not always be $1.$ Consider the ring $(R,+,\cdot)$ where $\forall a,b\in R, a+b := a+b-1 \wedge a\cdot b := a+b-ab.$ The additive identity is $1,$ not $0,$ and the multiplicative identity is $0,$ not $1.$

Comment: There is no additively absorbing element in a ring, because then it wouldn't additively be a group, unless it is the zero ring.

Comment: Yes, that would be zero. But that's not additively absorbing, it is the identity. Absorbing is basically the opposite of the identity. $0$ is multiplicatively absorbing.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it sounds strange to say $1$ is notation for the additive identity in a ring

Comment: @Simon Fraser I have edited the question and replaced ring by semiring. Can you please revisit at your from >However, the additive identity $0$ is not additively absorbing. That would mean that $\forall a\in R,$ $0+a=a+0=0,$ which is obviously false. ..?

Comment: @Simon Fraser Anyways, i do not see any problems but, the minus symbol you used in >a+b := a+b-1 \wedge a\cdot b := a+b-ab is bit confusing in case of semiring

Comment: @Simon Fraser Cool down please. Why should i downvote?

Comment: @gete for every a, isn't there a $1-a?$